# Selector Stats missing from Performance tab in Chrome, Opera & Edge

Tags: performance, css-selectors, web-inspector

I'm looking at articles like this one https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2023/01/17/the-truth-about-css-selector-performance/ to help me identify slow css selectors.

However I cannot see the Selector Stats tab in the Performance tab. It should be where the pink outline is.

I have ticked on Enable Advanced Rendering Instrumentation. It doesn't matter where I click, in Recalculate style or anywhere.

[image: Selector Stats missing from Performance tab in Chrome, Opera & Edge]

It's the same on my Chrome, Opera and Edge.
Thanks for any help
S :)

**EDIT**
This appears to be a bug https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/DevTools/issues/223